# Kaminari: paginate a scoped model. Controller/View responsibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm not sure i've entitled the question correctly.
In my project I have a categories controller with show action

```
def show
    @category = Category.find params[:id]
end
```

And in my view I render all the posts associated with this category

```
@category.posts.each do |post|
    link_to post.title, post
```

So now I want to add pagination with kaminari. 
I believe I could just change `@category.posts.each` to `@category.posts.page(params[:page]).each`, but I also think that this should be responsibility of the controller. Or am I wrong? Maybe it's totally fine?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your show method should look like this:

```
def show
  @posts = Category.find(params[:id]).posts.page(params[:page])
end
```

And in view:

```
@posts.each do |post|
```

Comment: Hey, methyl. I still need access to the @category (to make a title, etc). Should I just make two instance variables: @category and @posts?

Comment: Yes, you can do it and it will be totally clean and ok.